# How can I get the title of a drop down menu instead on value?

Tags: php

Normaly I would use $_POST['dorp_down_menu_name'] This gives me the id of the drop down menu. is there a trick to get the title of that value?

so if I have

```
<select name="dorp_down_menu_name">
    <option value="10">Title Goes Here</option>
</select>
```

I need to return "Title Goes Here" and not "10"

Comment: I think you meant `drop_down_menu_name` instead of `dorp_down_menu_name` - (`drop`) unless that's what you want ;-)

Comment: Your question is very vague. You should consider expanding it.

The best I can determine from what you've given us is that you want to capture what the user selected from the dropdown client side. BUT, you don't want the value of the select option, you want the title. Is that correct? If so, what javascript libraries do you have at your disposal (i.e. jquery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to be able to get both value and title you have two ways:

a) Create hidden element, that will be filled up by javasript with onSubmit event and will contain title.

b) You can serialize this upon building, like value="Title Goes Here:::10" and later split by :::, but only in case when you sure, that ::: or any other split-combination cannot be met in in the original text

Comment: Based on other feedback I have to use javascript

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to just make the value of the `<option>` be the value you want on the server side. there is no reason you can't do this:

```
<option value="Title Goes Here">Title Goes Here</option>
```

Comment: correct answer, but OP needs to ask himself what happens if two items have the exact same title

Comment: what if the OP needs to retain the id in the value property for other reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean client-side, you could make use of jquery:

```
var selectedText = $('[name="dorp_down_menu_name"]').find(":selected").text();
```

Another option would be to use the data pseudo property:

```
<option value="10" data-title="Title goes here">Title goes here</option>
```